# Determine diagonalizability by finding eigenvectors

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, diagonalization

> Let $$A = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 2 \\ 0 & 0 & 3 \end{pmatrix},$$ where $A \in M_{3 \times 3} (\Bbb R)$. Test $A$ for diagonalizability.

$$\det(A-\operatorname{\lambda I})=\det \begin{pmatrix} 1-\lambda & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1-\lambda & 2 \\ 0 & 0 & 3-\lambda \end{pmatrix}=(1-\lambda)^2(3-\lambda).$$

Compare algebraic and geometric multiplicity.

For $\lambda=1$, I get the eigenvector $\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}$, and for $\lambda=3$, I get $\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 2 \\ 2 \end{pmatrix}$

Since we can't find enough eigenvectors to fill the eigenspace for $3 \times 3$ matrix, it is not diagonalizable.

Am I on the right track? Also, for an eigenvalue with algebraic multiplicity of, say, $2$ , must it have $2$ independent eigenvectors? But I can only find $1$.

Comment: "*For an eigenvalue with algebraic multiplicity of, say, $2$, must it have $2$ independent eigenvectors?*"  No.  That is why we also refer to the *geometric multiplicity* of the eigenvalue noting that the geometric multiplicity is always between $1$ and the algebraic multiplicity but is not necessarily equal to the algebraic multiplicity.

Comment: Since the matrix is upper triangular you can read off the eigenvalues on the diagonal.

Comment: You need to be able to get a linearly independent set of eigenvectors. Since $1$ has multiplicity two this may be an issue, so look at $\ker (A -I)$ and determine the dimension.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your calculation of the eigenvalues and eigenvectors is correct, and your conclusion that $A$ is not diagonalizable is also correct.

$A$ is diagonalizable iff the geometric multiplicity of every eigenvalue is equal to its algebraic multiplicity. The eigenvalue $\lambda = 1$ has algebraic multiplicity $2$, but geometric multiplicity $1 \neq 2$, so (as you ask at the end) there should necessarily be two independent eigenvectors, which is not the case.

Comment: so the number of eigenvector for an eigenvalue is equal to geometric multiplicity?

Comment: To each eigenvalue corresponds an eigenspace, this is the vector space containing all eigenvectors to this eigenvalue and the zero vector. The dimension of this space is defined to be the geometric multiplicity, so this is the number of  elements of a basis of this space, i.e., the maximal number of linearly independent eigenvectors.